# If {$A_i$} and {$B_i$} are families of sets then

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- Prove-($\bigcup\limits_{i}A_i$) $\bigcap $($\bigcup\limits_{j}B_j$)=$\bigcup\limits_{i,j}(A_i \bigcap B_j)$
- Prove-($\bigcap\limits_{i}A_i$) $\bigcup $($\bigcap\limits_{j}B_j$)=$\bigcap\limits_{i,j}(A_i \bigcup B_j)$
- If {$I_j$} is a family of sets  with  domain J,say;$\Bbb K$=$\bigcup\limits_{j}I_j$,and let {$A_k$} be the family of sets  with  domain $\Bbb K$ then prove $\bigcup\limits_{k\in\mathbb K } A_k$=$\bigcup\limits_{j\in\mathbb J}$($\bigcup\limits_{i\in\mathbb I_j}A_i$)

These exercises are from *Halmos' Naive set theory* text.Actually these arose while dealing with some theorems related to *Measure theory*.I'm not very good in set theory.I tried these via ven diagram,but unable to visualize them.

I need help in visualising the above problems  through  venn diagrams also in proving them analytically.

Comment: A venn diagram with potentially infinitely many circles must look very confusing...  Try proving double containment.  Prove that the left side is a subset of the right side and vice versa.

Comment: You can prove these equations considering elements of sets and quantifiers.

Comment: I've removed inappropriate tags - [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory) and [measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) are specific branches of mathematics unrelated to this question, and the set theory tag is [reserved for questions at a higher level](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/set-theory/info).

Answer (score 0):

$x\in\left(\cup_iA_i\right)\cap\left(\cup_iB_i\right)\Leftrightarrow x\in\left(\cup_iA_i\right)$ and $x\in\left(\cup_iB_i\right)\Leftrightarrow x\in A_i$ for some $i$ and $x\in B_j$ for some $j\Leftrightarrow x\in A_i\cap B_j$ for some $i,j\Leftrightarrow x\in\cup_{i,j}A_i\cap B_j$. The second and third problems are solved similarly (most problems like this are, just a brute force showing that if $x$ is in one set it's in the other and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

When proving the equality of sets $S = T$, you usually

- let $s \in S$ and prove that $s \in T$, which means $S \subseteq T$, and
- let $t \in T$ and prove that $t \in S$, which means $T \subseteq S$, and
- since $S \subseteq T \subseteq S$, it follows $S=T$.

Let's do this for your first one and you can try the rest yourself. So we want to show that
$$
\left(\bigcup_{i}A_i\right) \cap \left(\bigcup_{j} B_j\right)
 = \bigcup_{i,j}\left(A_i \cap B_j\right)
$$
so let $x \in \left(\bigcup_{i}A_i\right) \cap \left(\bigcup_{j} B_j\right)$. Therefore, $x \in \bigcup_{i}A_i $ and $x \in \bigcup_{j} B_j$. Hence, $\exists m,n$ such that $x \in A_m$ and $x \in B_n$. Thus, $x \in A_m \cap B_n$, and so $x \in \bigcup_{i,j}\left(A_i \cap B_j\right)$ as desired.

Now assume $x \in \bigcup_{i,j}\left(A_i \cap B_j\right)$. Then, $\exists m,n$ such that $x \in A_m$ and $x \in B_n$. (can you finish this?)